# Are there HPC clould services?

Tags: cloud-computing

Is there some company providing HPC cluster online? So that I can connect to their cluster by Internet and run my program?

Comment: If you are interested in European providers, [Ovh has its own service too](https://www.ovh.ie/hpc/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Amazon Web Services has [HPC instances](http://aws.amazon.com/hpc/). Penguin Computing provides [Penguin On Demand](https://pod.penguincomputing.com/).

Almost all academic and non-commercial HPC services are available over the Internet as well. For example, the site I work for, [TACC](http://www.tacc.utexas.edu), provides its services through the Internet.

Comment: Please tell me that you didn't just say that TACC is an HPC cloud.

Comment: @Jeff, unless you define Cloud as synonymous with virtualization, then I don't see why not. Further, we've got 3 virtualized systems deployed or in deployment. We're as cloudy as anything else.

Comment: It's not just me :-)  From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing: "The main enabling technology for cloud computing is virtualization."  From http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-virtualization-with-cloud-computing.html: "Any discussion of cloud computing typically begins with virtualization. Virtualization is critical to cloud computing..."  In short, I do not see cloud computing as synonymous with hardware-as-a-service.

Comment: @Jeff, you're not the boss of me! Also, if you require virtualization, then you eliminate lots of HPC use cases due to the pretty much guaranteed memory bandwidth hit you're going to take due to the lack of control over placement. Also, OP doesn't seem to care about virtualization, so I ran with his definition. You'll note that his primary interest appears to be in connecting to remote HPC as a service not HPC with VMs.

Answer (score 5):

You could also take a look at [Rescale](https://www.rescale.com)--a web-based, on-demand HPC computing platform.