# Is it Grid/Cluster/Cloud Computing? How are those terms defined?

Tags: reference-request, hpc, terminology, cloud-computing

There are three very connected and widely used terms:

1. *Grid* and *grid computing*
2. *Cluster* and *cluster computing*
3. *Cloud* and *cloud computing*

In many situations, it is not obvious which term to use, as I fail to find an easy to use, laconic, precise set of criteria which would separate those terms.

The reference I know about is

- [N. Sadashiv and S. N. Dilip Kumar, "Cluster, grid and cloud computing: A detailed comparison," in *6th Int. Conf. Comp. Sci. Education*, Singapore, Aug. 2011, pp. 477–482](https://doi.org/10.1109/ICCSE.2011.6028683). Also available [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.465.8919&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

This reference (pretty well cited) provides detailed definitions and a comparison table; however, I find it hard to formulate "laymen's" definitions and criteria based on it. Probably, I am missing some very well-known publication that is used much more frequent.

I am looking for such simple definitions/criteria and reference(s) to ensure it's not an opinion-based question.

Comment: discussion [in the comments here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/17611/20688) is also relevant

Comment: I share the confusion about these terms, so im no expert. To me grid- and cluster computing refer to technically the same thing, i.e. a large computer that has a multitude of computing cores which have to do networking between them. When talking about a cluster it might be implied that several institutions combine their resources, but its still networked computers in the end. Cloud computing to me is connotated with running a program in an external server where you may have no clue where it is, or how big it is etc, mostly in a comercial setting. I agree that the definition is vague at best.